# Crash log sent by Apple cannot be symbolized correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I submitted the app to Apple Review and was told it would crash.
And I received the crashlog.txt from Apple.

I used a command like the following in terminal.app to symbolize the log.

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v ~/Desktop/clash_log.txt ~/Desktop/TestApp.app.dSYM > crash.txt
```

The result of symbolizing with the above command is as follows.

```
    {"app_name":"TestApp","timestamp":"2021-05-25 20:26:46.00 -0700","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx","adam_id":00000000,"build_version":"2","platform":2,"bundleID":"TestApp","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.5 (18E199)","incident_id":"FD178D30-6E7E-4F1A-B6A8-A38F57B1238A","name":"TestApp"}
    Incident Identifier: xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
    CrashReporter Key:   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
    Process:             TestApp [959]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/TestApp.app/TestApp
    Identifier:          TestApp
    Version:             2 (1.0.0)
    AppStoreTools:       12E262
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Foreground
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    Coalition:           TestApp [763]
    
    
    Date/Time:           2021-05-25 20:26:45.5716 -0700
    Launch Time:         2021-05-25 20:26:45.4202 -0700
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.5 (18E199)
    Release Type:        User
    Baseband Version:    n/a
    Report Version:      104
    
    Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a34d8acc
    Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
    Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
    Terminating Process: exc handler [959]
    Triggered by Thread:  6
    
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0:
    0   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae602a8 0x1dae1e000 + 271016
    1   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae6020c 0x1dae1e000 + 270860
    2   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae5f418 0x1dae1e000 + 267288
    3   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae2547c 0x1dae1e000 + 29820
    4   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a11ec664 0x1a11d1000 + 112228
    5   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a14ed6a8 0x1a11d1000 + 3262120
    6   CoreText                        0x00000001a3cb25a4 0x1a3c61000 + 333220
    7   CoreText                        0x00000001a3c9dca8 0x1a3c61000 + 249000
    8   CoreText                        0x00000001a3cb0d10 0x1a3c61000 + 326928
    9   CoreText                        0x00000001a3c7fef0 0x1a3c61000 + 126704
    10  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c835b4 0x1a3c61000 + 140724
    11  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c9d60c 0x1a3c61000 + 247308
    12  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c9d47c 0x1a3c61000 + 246908
    13  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c889ec 0x1a3c61000 + 162284
    14  UIFoundation                    0x00000001a8b60250 0x1a8b2e000 + 205392
    15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2834bc0 0x1a176a000 + 17607616
    16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe63c 0x1a176a000 + 3753532
    17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5407ec 0x19f53c000 + 18412
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f542084 0x19f53c000 + 24708
    19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe5ac 0x1a176a000 + 3753388
    20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1aff120 0x1a176a000 + 3756320
    21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1aff298 0x1a176a000 + 3756696
    22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe6b8 0x1a176a000 + 3753656
    23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe92c 0x1a176a000 + 3754284
    24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afed44 0x1a176a000 + 3755332
    25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b010d8 0x1a176a000 + 3764440
    26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b0179c 0x1a176a000 + 3766172
    27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b088e8 0x1a176a000 + 3795176
    28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2834a88 0x1a176a000 + 17607304
    29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2875c20 0x1a176a000 + 17873952
    30  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a2cfc91c 0x1a2b95000 + 1472796
    31  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a2cfce00 0x1a2b95000 + 1474048
    32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2861c74 0x1a176a000 + 17792116
    33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b06328 0x1a176a000 + 3785512
    34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af41b0 0x1a176a000 + 3711408
    35  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af1b08 0x1a176a000 + 3701512
    36  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af7ea0 0x1a176a000 + 3727008
    37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af1664 0x1a176a000 + 3700324
    38  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1aee984 0x1a176a000 + 3688836
    39  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2375d7c 0x1a176a000 + 12631420
    40  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2375444 0x1a176a000 + 12629060
    41  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2376348 0x1a176a000 + 12632904
    42  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2387888 0x1a176a000 + 12703880
    43  TestApp                     0x0000000100a66618 AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 75288 (<compiler-generated>:0)
    44  TestApp                     0x0000000100a6688c @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 75916 (<compiler-generated>:0)
    45  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2330a08 0x1a176a000 + 12347912
    46  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a233249c 0x1a176a000 + 12354716
    47  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a23385e8 0x1a176a000 + 12379624
    48  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198c598 0x1a176a000 + 2237848
    49  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1ef5634 0x1a176a000 + 7910964
    50  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198d130 0x1a176a000 + 2240816
    51  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198cb38 0x1a176a000 + 2239288
    52  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198cf40 0x1a176a000 + 2240320
    53  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198c77c 0x1a176a000 + 2238332
    54  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1994cc0 0x1a176a000 + 2272448
    55  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1e0304c 0x1a176a000 + 6918220
    56  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1f0e444 0x1a176a000 + 8012868
    57  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a19949b8 0x1a176a000 + 2271672
    58  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a17bc8a0 0x1a176a000 + 338080
    59  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a17bb220 0x1a176a000 + 332320
    60  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a17bc4c8 0x1a176a000 + 337096
    61  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2336788 0x1a176a000 + 12371848
    62  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1e2c6ac 0x1a176a000 + 7087788
    63  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeeaf5d8 0x1aeea5000 + 42456
    64  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeedad44 0x1aeea5000 + 220484
    65  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeebe6a4 0x1aeea5000 + 104100
    66  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeedaa0c 0x1aeea5000 + 219660
    67  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5407ec 0x19f53c000 + 18412
    68  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5442dc 0x19f53c000 + 33500
    69  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aef02fa0 0x1aeea5000 + 384928
    70  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aef02c30 0x1aeea5000 + 384048
    71  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aef03184 0x1aeea5000 + 385412
    72  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8cd848 0x19f82a000 + 669768
    73  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8cd744 0x19f82a000 + 669508
    74  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8cca48 0x19f82a000 + 666184
    75  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c6a28 0x19f82a000 + 641576
    76  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c61c0 0x19f82a000 + 639424
    77  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b6eae734 0x1b6eab000 + 14132
    78  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a23347e4 0x1a176a000 + 12363748
    79  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a233a054 0x1a176a000 + 12386388
    80  TestApp                     0x0000000100a5dcc4 main + 40132 (AppDelegate.swift:9)
    81  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019f582cf8 0x19f581000 + 7416

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 1:
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5521b0 0x19f53c000 + 90544
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f551ec4 0x19f53c000 + 89796
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5527a8 0x19f53c000 + 92072
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea752768 0x1ea74f000 + 14184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea75974c 0x1ea74f000 + 42828

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cd28c4fc 0x1cd288000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cd28b884 0x1cd288000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8ccd10 0x19f82a000 + 666896
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c6bb0 0x19f82a000 + 641968
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c61c0 0x19f82a000 + 639424
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a0ba6fac 0x1a0b9f000 + 32684
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a0ba6e78 0x1a0b9f000 + 32376
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a23e938c 0x1a176a000 + 13104012
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a0d182fc 0x1a0b9f000 + 1544956
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea750c00 0x1ea74f000 + 7168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759758 0x1ea74f000 + 42840

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a34d8acc 0x1a34a1000 + 228044
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a34d8acc 0x1a34a1000 + 228044
2   TestApp                     0x0000000100ae6fdc closure #2 in ViewController.viewDidLoad() + 602076 (<compiler-generated>:0)
3   TestApp                     0x0000000100ae701c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Bool) -> () + 602140 (<compiler-generated>:0)
4   TCC                             0x00000001e2a02924 0x1e29ff000 + 14628
5   TCC                             0x00000001e2a06ff0 0x1e29ff000 + 32752
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001ea785168 0x1ea76a000 + 110952
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001ea778a70 0x1ea76a000 + 60016
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f540874 0x19f53c000 + 18548
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f55cf54 0x19f53c000 + 134996
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f552d1c 0x19f53c000 + 93468
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea7527dc 0x1ea74f000 + 14300
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea75974c 0x1ea74f000 + 42828

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x8000000100b80ab0   x1: 0x0000000282c3ee80   x2: 0x0000000000000007   x3: 0x00000001aef3d238
    x4: 0x00000000000062dc   x5: 0x000000016f6ee5b0   x6: 0x0000000000000073   x7: 0x0000000000000850
    x8: 0x000000000000007f   x9: 0x00000000000007fb  x10: 0x00000000000007fd  x11: 0x000000000000005e
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x00000000ae00203b  x14: 0x00000000ae202800  x15: 0x0000000000002800
   x16: 0x000000002e200000  x17: 0x00000001aef449b0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x8000000100b80ab0
   x20: 0x000000016f6ee640  x21: 0x0000000100b7a0f4  x22: 0x0000000000000028  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x00000000000005ee  x25: 0x000000000000000b  x26: 0x0000000000000002  x27: 0x0000000100b80060
   x28: 0x000000016f6ee680   fp: 0x000000016f6ee730   lr: 0x00000001a34d8acc
    sp: 0x000000016f6ee680   pc: 0x00000001a34d8acc cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault
```

This result does not exactly match the crash log received from Apple, but it is not fully symbolized.

As far as I read the above log, I can only understand that there may be a problem around the 9th line of AppDelegate.swift.
The 9th line of the actual AppDelegate.swift is just the place where the class definition is as follows.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SwiftyStoreKit
import Foundation



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

What is the cause of the inability to symbolize correctly?
Here's one of the causes I can think of:

This XCode project uses a third-party library, so "Enable Bitcode" is set to No.

Perhaps because of that, when I press "Download Debug Symbols", "No dSYMs were found for Version ..." is displayed.

I suspect this is one of the reasons why crash logs cannot be symbolized correctly.

[image]

Please let me know if there is a way to properly symbolize the crash log or to know the cause of the crash correctly.